# Search for duplicates in a Hash Map and print out the number of instances

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using to a Hashmap to store the result set .

```
HashMap<String,Integer> hMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

String existsUser = "select NAME" +" from Details where MEMID =" + memid;
rs = stmt.executeQuery(existsUser);
```

This is the sample DB

NAME:
JACK
JILL
JOHN
JACK

I need to display the number of occurrences of each name separately, How do i do it ?
eg: Jack-2  , Jill -1

I currently have this code :

```
 if(count == 0) {
hMap.put(rs.getString("NAME"),1); //get the string 

   }else {
hMap.put(rs.getString("NAME"),count +1); 
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be done from different SQL query.

```
String existsUser = "SELECT name, count(*) AS occurances FROM Details WHERE memid = " + memid + " GROUP BY name";
```

The result set will have two columns "name" and "occurances". You straight away get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Integer> names = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
// sample loop for illustration; loop over your ResultSet if you wish
for String name : results) {
    if (names.containsKey(name) {
       int count = names.get(name);
       names.put(name, ++count);
    } else {
        names.put(name, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashmaps can't have duplicates...

If you want to track duplicates in map, then use the item as the key and the occurences as the value.

Everytime you see a key more than once increase the counter (the value of the key).

If you haven't seen it insert and set the key to 1

Comment: You are correct, of course.  That's what I thought s/he meant at first, but I believe s/he's referring to the ResultSet having dupes.

Comment: I agree the question is a bit ambiguous. Maybe the op can reword?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, Integer> hMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String name = rs.get("NAME");
        int count = hMap.containsKey(name) ? hMap.get(name) : 0;
        hMap.put(name, count + 1);
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : hMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "-" + entry.getValue());
    }
```